# Bitmap fast operation in Android

Tags: android, performance, optimization, android-ndk, skia

Here is what i am doing...

1. Convert image from camera feed which in YUV_ byte array
2. Rotate image at angle (angle is dynamic. it`s value will be 1-180)
3. Scale image
4. Save image to sd-card

All above thing are going well.But above whole process take around 400 ms per camera feed.

Is their any way to decrease time. 
I build skia-2d library because android use it in his framework for image. But unable to use it. it need some android library support like GraphicsJNI and CreateJavaOutputStreamAdaptor etc and both these are changed in every android os version.

Did any body have idea/way to optimize bitmap?....

Comment: You need to time the operations separately to spot the bottelneck. Is there a combined rotate+scale function ? What language/library/processor ?

Comment: They all are separate process, This is done by Bitmap,YuvJpeg and BitmapFactory of Android-Java classes...

Comment: What API level are you targeting?  What level of quality do you need on the saved images?  For API 18+, you can do all items quickly with OpenGL ES and the video encoder ("save image to SD card" will go much faster if you record it as MPEG video).  See "Show + capture camera" in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika), demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH9kCP2T5Gg -- can do live filtering / scaling / recording at 30fps.

Comment: API level in 2.3 but if really not thing happen in 2.3 then i can shift to API-14. Because we want maximum user for this app.